# Streaming REST responses with nestled streams

Tags: rest, jersey, jackson, streaming, jax-rs

I have a scenario that I would like to get a wider input on before implementing and trying different solutions.

A REST service I'm implementing will be serving a model containing several fields of binary data and also simple strings. An easy way would just be to implement POJOS containing my String, byte[] fields etc. Jackson would then serialise it for me using base64. Piece of cake.

But I would like to service this as a stream. The binary fields will be pretty huge and are already handled as streams incoming from another external resource within my service. Thus reading them into byte arrays and then letting jackson convert them to base64 would impose a not-acceptable performance hit.

Maybe I can simply have OutputStream objects within my POJO. Would that make Jackson stream it through (whilst encoding to base64) or would it just read the the whole stream first anyways? Maybe Jackson doesn't support this at all?

Another option might be using a multi part response, but not sure Jersey will not buffer it all up too?

Or would the only way to do it is to use some kind of custom jackson serializer? 
Could I maybe use the StreamingOutput to perform this?

If it would just been one blob I would simply return it as an octet-stream and be happy, but as mentioned I have a data model with several binary and non-binary fields and I would really like to return it all in one call.

So what do you say? What's the easiest/best way to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a possible way to proceed if anyone is interested.

In the DTO class I can use fields of type of InputStream and set them to use a custom serializer:

```
public class ModelDTO {
    private String someString;
    private String someOtherString;
    @JsonSerialize(using = InputStreamSerializer.class)
    private InputStream firstBlob;
    @JsonSerialize(using = InputStreamSerializer.class)
    private InputStream secondBlob;
...
}
```

And the serializer:

```
public class InputStreamSerializer extends JsonSerializer<InputStream> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(InputStream inputStream, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeBinary(Base64Variants.MIME_NO_LINEFEEDS, inputStream, -1);
    }
}
```

I haven't confirmed it completely but from what I can see Jackson will write this to the OutputStream using only a buffer, thus not buffering the whole incoming stream if it's huge.

So this is a (very simple) solution to my problem, but if anyone has other suggestions I'm very open to hear them.